# Choose between Keras and TensorFlow for a beginner?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a doubt, Keras seems easy to implement compared to TensorFlow. Are there things we can do with Tensorflow but not with Keras?

Comment: Hi! To get better feedback, you should review: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keras is a high level api which works on top of Tensorflow. It is very easy to learn and implement. Tensorflow allows us to change every minute detail in the network. Thus making it useful in scenarios where flexibility is essential. But building a network and debugging it in Tensorflow is more time consuming than Keras. So use Keras when you want to build a model in a less amount of time, or when you want to test how good a architecture is. Use Tensorflow when you want to get your hands dirty by changing every parameter there is. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think, Keras is more like a deep learning interface, built on a third-party framework. Its drawback is that overencapsulation obviously leads to a loss of flexibility. Keras is easy to implement quickly. It is recommended that you implement the model on Keras first, while familiarizing yourself with how TensorFlow implements the same content.